# How do I fix this issue, Index out of range?

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through the items of a list in a loop by using i+1 but I get the error "Index out of range". I cant do i-1 because it will loop back to the last item of my list. How can I fix this error?

```
C = int(input())
cInt1 = list(map(int, input().split()))
cInt2 = list(map(int, input().split()))

counter = 0


for i in range(C):
    if cInt1[i] == 1:
        counter+=3
        if cInt1[i+1] == 1:
            counter-=1
        else:
            print("hi")

for i in range(C):
    if cInt2[i] == 1:
        counter+=3
        if cInt2[i+1] == 1:
            counter-=1

for i in range(0, C, 2):
    if cInt2[i] == 1 and cInt2[i] == 1:
        counter-=1

print(counter)
```

input:

```
5
1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

Expected output:

```
9

Output: list Index out of range
```

Comment: On the last loop iteration, `cInt1[i+1]` will definitely be out of range.  It would help if you explained what you _want_ to do in this case.

Comment: What do you want your code to do when it's on the final element? (When `i == 4`, there isn't a `cInt2[i+1]`, it simply won't exist)

Comment: `cInt2[i] == 1 and cInt2[i] == 1` why double check

Answer (score 0):

You can check that i + 1 is not out of the range of your lists as such:

```py
if i+1 < len(cInt1) and cInt1[i+1] == 1: # note the added conditional
    counter-=1
else:
    print("hi")

...

if i+1 < len(cInt2) and cInt2[i+1] == 1: # note the added conditional
    counter-=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking for a value for C, it would be safer to use `for item in cInt1:`

Instead of using `i+1`, it would be safer to use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

```
for i, j in itertools.zip_longest(cInt1, cInt1[1:]):
    if i == 1:
        counter+=3
        if j == 1:
            counter-=1
        else:
            print("hi")

for i, j in itertools.zip_longest(cInt2, cInt2[1:]):
    if i == 1:
        counter+=3
        if j == 1:
            counter-=1

for i, j in zip(cInt1[::2], cInt2[::2]):
    if i == 1 and j == 1:
        counter-=1

print(counter)
```